# How to avoid repetitions within Angular ngClass?

Tags: angular, styling, ng-class, angular-ng-class

Imagine following situation:

```
 <div *ngFor="let d of dm; first as first">
    <span
      [ngClass]="{ cSmall: !first, cGray: !first, cTab1: !first }"
    >
      {{ d }}
    </span>
  </div>
```

All these CSS-Classes `cSmall, cGray, cTab1` are depended on `!first`.

Can I avoid unnecessary repetitions within:

```
{ cSmall: !first, cGray: !first, cTab1: !first }
```

I've alredy tried `{ [cSmall,cGray,cTab1]: !first }` with no success :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

Reference : [NgClass API](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `[ngClass]="{ 'cSmall cGray cTab1': !first }"`